# JAVA8 - Grouping with lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I have a collection with structure like this:

```
@Entity
public class RRR{

    private Map<XClas, YClas> xySets;

}
```

and `XClas` has a field called `ZZZ`

my question is:
I would like to aggregate it with lambda to get a `Map<ZZZ, List<RRR>>`.

Is it possible? Now I'm stuck with:

```
Map xxx = rrrList.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(x->x.xySets().entrySet().stream().collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(y->y.getKey().getZZZ()))));
```

but it's `Map<Map<ZZZ, List<XClas>>, List<RRR>>` so it's not what I was looking for :)

Right now just to make it work, I did aggregation with two nested loops, but it would be so great, if you could help me make it done with lambdas.

**EDIT**

I post what I got by now, as asked.
I already left nested loops, and I manage to work my way up to this point:

```
Map<ZZZ, List<RRR>> temp;
rrrList.stream().forEach(x -> x.getxySetsAsList().stream().forEach(z -> {
            if (temp.containsKey(z.getKey().getZZZ())){
                List<RRR> uuu = new LinkedList<>(temp.get(z.getKey().getZZZ()));
                uuu.add(x);
                temp.put(z.getKey().getZZZ(), uuu);
            } else {
                temp.put(z.getKey().getZZZ(), Collections.singletonList(x));
            }
        }));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `assignments`? A `Collection` of `RRR`? Also can you provide the working version with the `for` loops?

Comment: It's corrected now - sorry bout that

Comment: RRR, XXX, ZZZ, uuu, xySets, ... It's hard do resist the urge to -1 that just for these names and the incomplete class descriptions.

Comment: `getxySetsAsList()`, list of the keys or the values? It looks like a list of `Entry` but you only use the key.

Comment: I've been trying to come up with a clever way to do this, but the longer I think about it, the more I am convinced that you should just stick to a plain old pre-Java8 nested loop.

Comment: I'm trying hard too, but the naming convention is too much for me. @LuciusSnow have you tried with `Collectors.reducing()`?

Comment: I'm using only key, cause I want to aggregate by key value of map.
@Marco13 : sorry bout that - I can't public my code and/or parts of it to anyone - company policy :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried around a bit and found the following solution, posting it here just as another example:

```
rrrList.stream().map(x -> x.xySets).map(Map::entrySet).flatMap(x -> x.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getKey().getZZZ(), 
        Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

The first line could also be written as `rrrList.stream().flatMap(x -> x.xySets.entrySet().stream())` which might be found more readable.
Here is self-contained example code for those wanting to play around themselves:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<RRR> rrrList = Arrays.asList(new RRR(), new RRR(), new RRR());
    System.out.println(rrrList);
    Stream<Entry<XClas, YClas>> sf = rrrList.stream().map(x -> x.xySets).map(Map::entrySet).flatMap(x -> x.stream());
    Map<ZZZ, List<YClas>> res = sf.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getKey().getZZZ(), Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
    System.out.println(res);
}

public static class RRR {
    static XClas shared = new XClas();
    private Map<XClas, YClas> xySets = new HashMap<>();
    RRR() { xySets.put(shared, new YClas()); xySets.put(new XClas(), new YClas()); }
    static int s = 0; int n = s++; 
    public String toString() { return "RRR" + n + "(" + xySets + ")"; }
}
public static class XClas {
    private ZZZ zzz = new ZZZ();
    public ZZZ getZZZ() { return zzz; }
    public String toString() { return "XClas(" + zzz + ")"; } 
    public boolean equals(Object o) { return (o instanceof XClas) && ((XClas)o).zzz.equals(zzz); }
    public int hashCode() { return zzz.hashCode(); }
}
public static class YClas {
    static int s = 0; int n = s++; 
    public String toString() { return "YClas" + n; }
}
public static class ZZZ { 
    static int s = 0; int n = s++ / 2;
    public String toString() { return "ZZZ" + n; }
    public boolean equals(Object o) { return (o instanceof ZZZ) && ((ZZZ)o).n == n; }
    public int hashCode() { return n; }
}
```

Comment: code does not compile :(
this line makes a problem:
`Map<ZZZ, List<YClas>> res = sf.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getKey().getZZZ(), Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));`

Comment: last collector makes an error : `Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList()` [link](http://speedy.sh/2qtFC/Bez-tytulu.png")

Comment: ok - your standalone example does not compile, but even though I decided to give it a try in my project. Funny thing - JetBrains IntelliJ marks this line I mentioned as an error, but whole projects compile (!), and even better - it's working :) I don't get it how, with marked error this is working, but it does :) and it's fast as hell:)

Comment: I am glad it finally works for you. I am using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_11 here. Eclipse Luna (and NetBeans 8) do not indicate any errors.

Comment: updating my IDE helped for error message - IntelliJ 13.1.4 got full support for Java8 - 13.0.4. only partial support. That was reason why I got so much trouble figuring it out on my own :/ Bollocks... Still thank you very much for your time :)

Answer (score 5):

Something like that? :

```
    Map<ZZZ, List<RRR>> map = new HashMap<>();

    list.stream().forEach(rrr -> {
        rrr.xySets.keySet().stream().forEach(xclas -> {
            if (!map.containsKey(xclas.zzz))
                map.put(xclas.zzz, new ArrayList<RRR>());
            map.get(xclas.zzz).add(rrr);
        });
    });
```

Comment: +1, since it works, but is there _any_ benefit compared to using a good old-fashioned double-for-loop?

Comment: lambda expressions are/should be faster and more efficient.

Comment: I'm sorry, but after few other answers, there is much better answer, with only lambda used for aggregation. And, what's most important, the other solution is much faster than this. Still, thank you for your time:)

Answer (score 3):

Another way you could do this:

```
Map<Z, List<R>> map = rs.stream()
        .map(r -> r.xys.keySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.<X, Z, R>toMap(x -> x.z, x -> r, (a, b) -> a)))
        .map(Map::entrySet)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: what does `Collectors.<X, Z, R>toMap(x -> x.z, x -> r, (a, b) -> a))` mean? Code does not compile, and I have trouble understanding how it have to work, so I can't fix/customize it to my needs :(

Comment: @LuciusSnow I changed your names a bit when I was writing this, `X` is `XClas`, `Z` is `ZZZ`, `R` is `RRR`, `x.z` would be `x.getZZZ()`, and `r.xys.keySet()` is `r.xySets.keySet()`, does that solve your problem?

Comment: Now it works as charm:) sorry, I'm new to lambda. I know it's more than useful, so I'm doing my best to use it, but it's still bit to hard to read it sometimes :) thank you